# What to use (instead of C-x C-f) to open a UTF-8-encoded file?

Tags: emacs

I know that including a directive like `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` near the top of a file tells Emacs to assume a UTF-8 encoding, but more often than not, I want to open UTF-8-encoded files that do not include such a directive.  (In some cases, modifying the file to add the coding directive would not be a big deal, but even then this is a very unsatisfactory solution.)

> In such situations, what should I use (instead of plain `C-x C-f`) to open a file using UTF-8 as coding system?

EDIT: to be clear: even "modern Emacs" sometimes guesses the wrong coding system (possibly due to an error or corruption in the file); I want to tell Emacs: *when opening this file, ignore your heuristics, **assume** a UTF-8 coding*.  Basically, I want the equivalent of a `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` directive that does not require me to modify the file.

Comment: you don't need to do anything for utf-8 by default. What does `M-x describe-current-coding-system ENTER` show?

Comment: If you have a legacy `.emacs` file, it may contain code which was once recommended (pre version 22 or so) but which should now be disabled. Try moving your `.emacs` file out of the way; if it helps, you can try to identify which stanza is causing your problems.

Comment: This article may prove useful: [Working with Coding Systems and Unicode in Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2012/08/09/working-coding-systems-unicode-emacs/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try prefixing your command with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to manually specify the coding system. For example:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>`utf-8`<kbd>RET</kbd> *(tell emacs that the following command should use `utf-8`)*

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>`path/to/your/file`<kbd>RET</kbd> *(open the file)*

---

But as noted in the comments, this should normally not be necessary if your system is well configured.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, with modern Emacs you should not have to do anything for opening correctly an utf-8 encoded file.

That said look for `set-language-environment` in your .emacs, You could try to remove it, or to write:

```
(set-language-environment "utf-8")
```

For configuring Emacs to use utf-8 as default encoding.